# What is the physical meaning of the X,Y,Z channels of the Ambisonics B-format (FuMa, AmbiX)

Tags: ambisonics

I know that W channel records pressure, like any omni microphone does. But what do x, y and z channels contain?

Wikipedia page [Ambisonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambisonics) says:

> The B-format signals comprise a truncated spherical harmonic decomposition of the sound field. They correspond to the sound pressure W, and the three components of the pressure gradient X Y Z (not to be confused with the related particle velocity) at a point in space.

For a plane wave, the magnitude of pressure gradient relates to the pressure by a factor of omega/c (i.e., proportional to frequency), so the frequency responses of x, y and z channels should have a 1-st order slope compared to W. However, I made a measurement with my Zoom H3-VR (point source 0.5 meters to the left of the mic; ambiX format), and W and Y are mostly identical (from 200 Hz to 5 kHz; W is 4-5 dB lower than Y), there is no slope. So, is there a mistake in Wikipedia, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to understand it is to imagine the polar pattern of a figure-8 microphone.

A figure-8 microphone has two circular lobes positioned fore and aft of the capsule. Fore of the capsule is "in phase" and the aft lobe is "out of phase".

Figure-8 microphones sense pressure gradient information, which is the rate of change of acoustic pressure in a given direction.

Now imagine three of these figure-8 mics, positioned in exactly the same point in space. Not possible in reality, but certainly possible "virtually" which is effectively what the AMBIX/FUMA formats give you.

Each of these three "virtual" figure-8 mics are oriented at 90 degrees from each other, thus:

- Front+/Back- [X]
- Left+/Right- [Y]
- Up+/Down- [Z]

This covers all the orientations necessary for 1st Order Ambisonics, and when coupled with the "W" signal, which is also an omnidirectional mic placed at exactly the same point as all the other mics, you get your required 1st Order Ambisonic components.

Higher order Ambisonics require additional signals and is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't explain, what physical quantity is being recorded. What does a figure-8 microphone pick up exactly? (particle velocity? pressure gradient? something else?). And how does the level relate to the W microphone...

Comment: Another term for a figure-8 mic is a pressure gradient mic. Omni mic is a pressure transducer. XYZ encode the direction of the sound source, whereas the W does not. Wikipedia is not a source of information that you would want to cite and vetting it is beyond the scope of what we do here.

Comment: okay, "pressure gradient" lines up with wikipedia, but what is the relation between pressure gradient and pressure, in the magnitudes and frequency response? They are different units, at the very least... From my basic understanding, it is -i·omega·cos(theta)/c, where theta is the angle between wave direction and mic direction, but that doesn't match up with my measurements. I want to build my own ambisonics capture and reproduction systems, so it is pretty critical to understand it...

Comment: These are all separate questions. Please treat as such. Also understand that B-Format has nothing to do with mic direction. Capsule output is captured in A format, then translated to B-Format in a mic-dependent way. You are also encroaching on dsp/physics of this subject, which will probably be found to be out-of-scope and better addressed elsewhere.